# Python script not working with django shell

Tags: python, django, nameerror, urllib3, django-shell

i have written script to `create users` using csv file. i have to check the `sso username` is valid or not using an api request as well and its written in `_validate_user` function. To make the api request i'm using `urllib3`. Sample code provided below.

```
import csv
import urllib3.request
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def _validate_user(sso_username):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    fl_name = '<url>' + sso_username
    site_data = http.request('GET', fl_name)
    _data = site_data.data
    print(_data)

FILENAME = r'./csv/usernames.csv'

with atomic():
    with open(FILENAME, 'rt',  encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            user_name = row['username']
            if _validate_user(user_name):
                User.objects.get_or_create(
                    username=row['username'],
                    password='password',
                )
                print("User added")
            else:
                print("Invaid user")
```

when i run the code using `python3 manage.py shell` and input code line by line i'm not getting any error and everything is working as expected.

When i use `python3 manage.py shell < utility_folder/load_users.py` to run the script i'm getting `NameError: name 'urllib3' is not defined at line number 6`. What am i missing here. I tried with `requests` module also didn't do much help.

```
Django version is 1.11 and python 3.6
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `exec(open("utility_folder/load_users.py").read())` into the shell instead of `python3 manage.py shell < utility_folder/load_users.py`.

Comment: If you're going to do this more than once, consider creating a Django management command.

Comment: This is working, do you have any idea why the conventional way is not working ?